# Adding percentage to subtotal

Tags: javascript, autodesk

I am trying to write a script that will add 5% to a subtotal and no matter what I try it won't work. Here is an example. I know Excel formulas, but don't write Javascript, please help.

```js
// (Function added as source of dummy data)
function getField(key) {
    return ({
        EXTENSION1: {value:'110.0'},
        EXTENSION2: {value:'95.0'},
        EXTENSION3: {value:'85.0'},
        EXTENSION4: {value:'65.0'},
        EXTENSION5: {},
        'GE%': {value: '5'},
    })[key]
}

var extension1 = this.getField("EXTENSION1").value;
var extension2 = this.getField("EXTENSION2").value;
var extension3 = this.getField("EXTENSION3").value;
var extension4 = this.getField("EXTENSION4").value;
var extension5 = this.getField("EXTENSION5").value;

var sum = parseFloat(extension1) + parseFloat(extension2) + parseFloat(extension3) + parseFloat(extension4) + parseFloat(extension5);

var percentage = parseFloat(this.getField("GE%").value);

var result = sum * (percentage / 100);

console.log(result);
```

I've entered this code and it's not producing a value

[image]

Comment: You have to add the percentage back to the total: `sum + sum * percentage/100`

Comment: How have you determined this produces no result? How are you logging the value or `result`? What are the input values from `EXTENSIONX` and `GE%`?

Comment: You just set a value to a variable, but never output this value somewhere

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've edited my original post to show the fields I'm totaling. I need the field that's showing 355.00 to actually calculate the sum plus 5.5%. The formula/script that was given to me isn't calculating anything.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried that previously and still didn't get an answer

Comment: Perhaps you need to RETURN a value
`return result` instead of `console.log(result)`

Comment: You have no value for `EXTENSION5`. That produces the `NaN` result. You need to  skip or provide default values for the missing items.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this snippet to implement your solution and it works for me:

```js
let extension1 = 0;
let extension2 = 110;
let extension3 = 95;
let extension4 = 85;
let extension5 = 65;
let percentage = 5.5;

var sum = parseFloat(extension1) + parseFloat(extension2) + parseFloat(extension3) + parseFloat(extension4) + parseFloat(extension5);

var result = sum * ((100 + percentage) / 100);

console.log(result);
```

Key ideas:

- you should make sure that your extension values are proper values. If you have non-numeric values to any of them, the result will be `NaN`
- you multiply `sum` with `percentage / 100`, but you want to add that to `sum`, which means that you need `100 + percentage` instead of just `percentage
- make sure you use the `result`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't properly account for when a field hasn't been filled out.

### A better solution

You can use detect if a value is `NaN` and instead set it to 0. The parts I edited are between the markers.

```js
// (Function added as source of dummy data)
function getField(key) {
    return ({
        EXTENSION1: {value:'110.0'},
        EXTENSION2: {value:'95.0'},
        EXTENSION3: {value:'85.0'},
        EXTENSION4: {value:'65.0'},
        EXTENSION5: {},
        'GE%': {value: '5'},
    })[key]
}

var extension1 = this.getField("EXTENSION1").value;
var extension2 = this.getField("EXTENSION2").value;
var extension3 = this.getField("EXTENSION3").value;
var extension4 = this.getField("EXTENSION4").value;
var extension5 = this.getField("EXTENSION5").value;

// ------------------------
const inputArray = [
    extension1,
    extension2,
    extension3,
    extension4,
    extension5,
];
const sum = inputArray.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        let val = parseFloat(currentValue);
        if (isNaN(val)) {
            val = 0;
        }
        return accumulator + val;
    },
    0
);
// ------------------------

var percentage = parseFloat(this.getField("GE%").value);

var result = sum * (percentage / 100);

console.log(result);
```

### An okay solution

Your updated summation code could simply fail-over to `0` if the string is empty.

```js
var sum = parseFloat(extension1 || 0) + parseFloat(extension2 || 0) + parseFloat(extension3 || 0) + parseFloat(extension4 || 0) + parseFloat(extension5 || 0);
```

### Why?

Passing an empty string to `parseInt` results in `NaN`:

````js
parseFloat('')
> NaN

Likewise, `NaN` plus anything is still `NaN`:
```js
parseFloat('') + 1
> NaN
````